# jQuery append() - put li-tags to list

Tags: jquery, html, append

I have some ul with class

```
<ul class="class">

</ul>
```

And i have jquery script, that must put li-tags between ul-tags:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select option").each(function () {
        var m = $( this ).text();
        $("ul.class").append("<li>", m, "</li>");
  });
```

but its not works. when script is done, i see html like:

```
<ul class="class">
   <li></li>
   Option 1
   <li></li>
   Option 2
   <li></li>
   Option 3
</ul>
```

Comment: That's simply not how the jQuery API works. I suggest you carefully read the documentation for `.append()`. http://api.jquery.com/append

Comment: why dont you use         $("ul.class").append("<li>"+m+"</li>");

Comment: thanks very much and sorry for stupid question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("ul.class").append("<li>", m, "</li>");
```

should be

```
$("ul.class").append("<li>" + m + "</li>");
```

Answer (score 3):

use `$("ul.class").append("<li>"+m+"</li>");`

instead of

`$("ul.class").append("<li>" + m + "</li>");`.

By [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/append/), it "Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the end of each element in the set of matched elements". The Syntax is `.append( content [, content ] )` or you can use `.append( function(index, html) )`. The append can take any number of additional arguments.

Now what happens in  `$("ul.class").append("<li>" + m + "</li>");`, is each parameter will be taken as separate DOM content to attach. That is why your "`<li></li>`" is attached at first and then the "text". The "text" will be considered as an additional argument.

Answer (score 2):

I also recommend building the whole list of LI elements as a single string before passing it to append(..). It's more efficient to limit calls that will cause the browser to change the DOM structure to a single call.

Build the string in the loop and pass it to append after the loop

Ex: `$('ul').append('<li>option1'</li>.....<li>optionn<li>');`